# How to delete the matching line and the previous two lines in shell?

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file like below.

```
first line
second line
third line
fourth line
fifth line
```

How can I use a shell command to delete the matching line and the previous 2 lines? For example, I want to match the fourth line and delete the fourth, third, second lines. I got I can use `sed -i '/second/q' filename` to delete the lines after the matched line, but how to achieve delete the precious lines?

Comment: Could you please do add your efforts in form of code which is highly encouraged on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. Change `$0=="fourth line"` with string which you want to match in that specific line.

```
tac Input_file | 
awk -v line="4" -v skipLines="2" -v totLines=$(wc -l < Input_file) '
FNR==(totLines-line+1) && $0=="fourth line"{
  ++count
  next
}
count && count++<=skipLines{ next }
1
' | tac
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
tac Input_file |                     ##Using tac command to print contents from bottom to top.
awk -v line="4" -v skipLines="2" -v totLines=$(wc -l < Input_file) '
##passed tac output to awk program which has 3 variables in it.
##line is on which line you want to match for pattern, skipLines(how many lines you want to skip), totLines has total lines in Input_file
FNR==(totLines-line+1) && $0=="fourth line"{
##Checking if current line is which we are looking for and its same as needed pattern.
  ++count                            ##Increasing count with 1 here.
  next                               ##next will skip all statements from here.
}
count && count++<=skipLines{ next }  ##Checking if count is NOT NULL and count is <= skipLines, when both are TRUE do next to skip lines.
1                                    ##1 will print the current line.
' | tac                              ##Sending awk output to tac to get it in its actual order.
```

***NOTE:*** Please make sure wherever there is Input_file you could place your actual file's name there.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed solution.  I've tried your solution, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure is there any mistake I made, but I just copy your command sentence and modify the file name. Can you have a check?

Answer (score 0):

An awk-only version:

```
$ awk -v p=3
{
    b[FNR%(p+1)]=$0                 # p+1 sized modulo implemented circular buffer b
    if(((FNR+1)%(p+1)) in b)        # print the one to be overwritten next
        print b[(FNR+1)%(p+1)]      # ... if it exist
}
/fourth line/ {                     # when match met
    delete b                        # reset time for b
}
END {                               # in the end
    for(i=1;i<=(p+1);i++)           # we flush all the values left in buffer
        if(((FNR+i)%(p+1)) in b)
            print b[(FNR+i)%(p+1)]
}
```

Output:

```
first line
fifth line
```